# SOLR - Use single text field in schema for full text search

Tags: solr, full-text-search, schema

I am getting familiar with SOLR.

I would like to use SOLR for full text search for many kind of entities. I don't want to create a Document for every different type of entity. I don't want to be able to search for specific fields. I am only interested in that if a specified string is anywhere in any item.

In database terms for example I have a table News and a table Employee and I want to search for the word 'apple', I don't mind in which field it is, I only want to get back the database ID from the records which contain it.

Could it be a solution, that I use a SOLR schema something like this:

```
<fields>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
   <field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
</fields>
```

So, I only need an ID and the contents. I put all the data, in which I want to be able search into one 'content' field. When I search for some words it looks for it in the 'id' and int the 'content'.

Is this a good idea? Any performance or design problem?

Thanks,
Tamas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields. It says:

A common requirement is to copy or merge all input fields into a single solr field. This can be done as follows:-

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text"/>
```

That's typically what is done to search across multiple fields.

But if you don't even want your original fields, just concatenate all your fields into one big field `content` and index in Solr. There should be no problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either copyField to text (see example in the distribution) and have that set as default field ("df" parameter in solrconfig.xml for the select handler).

Or, if you anticipate more complex requirements down the line and/or non-text searches, I would recommend looking at [eDismax with qf parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) and it will handle searching all those fields itself.